# Magento 2 : Related Products in product view page

Tags: magento2

Iam adding related products to particular product through admin in magento 2 but its not displaying in products view page.i want to show it in product view page. Can anyone help me

Comment: Remove the cache php bin/magento cache:clean, run index management, then check.

Comment: may be you are assigned products are  visibility option is Not Visibile Individually..Please check Once

Comment: cleaned cache it is in visible option only but not getting